# Batch file and using set parameters to log in

Tags: shell, batch-file

I'm I new to batch file creation, I am trying to open a application and log in. To check what parameter the application accepts I used:

```
start "C:\Program Files\Bitvise SSH Client" BvSsh.exe -h
```

As part of the return the following are accepted(along with others):

```
-host="" 
-user="" 
-password="" 
-loginOnStartup
```

I am not sure how to utilise these to actually login to the program? How would the batch file be structured?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\Program Files\Bitvise SSH Client\BvSsh.exe -user="<enter the username>" -password="<enter password>"
```

But usually it's not a good idea to store passwords as plain text in bat files...

I don't know the program you are using. Possibly you'll have to add `-loginOnStartup` at the end of the line. Also I don't know whether the parameter `host` is optional or not. However, just add the parameters if needed:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\Program Files\Bitvise SSH Client\BvSsh.exe -host="<enter host here>" -user="<enter the username>" -password="<enter password>" -loginOnStartup
```